# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again. on patch method

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

We are using outlook graph api for reading messages. The credentials and things are working fine.
But when we are using api with patch method it returns. *Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.*

The scope we are using *OFFICE365_SCOPES='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'*

```
   public function setMessageAsSeen($userName, $msgId){
        try{    
            if( ! $this->msLogin()){
                return [];
            }
            $ch = curl_init();
            $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/".$userName."/messages/".$msgId;
            $request_headers = array();
            $request_headers[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
            $request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->accessToken;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['isRead' => true]));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            dd($response);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);
            if($httpCode != 200) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Log::error('setMessageAsSeen() error : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        


    }
```

Request to please guide on same.

Answer (score 0):

`GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages` requires `Mail.ReadBasic.All`.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

---

`PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}` requires `Mail.ReadWrite`.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http